# How to use expression as argument as in e.g. t.test function

Tags: r, function, arguments, expression

I wrote a function to perform hypothesis testing. I will call it here `myMethod.test`. This function basically takes two samples x and y and returns a p value for my null hypothesis. I thus write a function :

```
myMethod.test<-function(x,y)
{.....}
```

I would like also to support expression as it is the case for base core test function e.g. t.test or wilcox.test in which you can write (`measurement` and `group` being two columns of data):

```
t.test(data,measurement~group)
```

I would like to find existing functions coded in pure R and supporting such call to adapt it to my case (or any other hints).

Comment: This is too broad to answer in general. It would be better if you provided a more concrete [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used for testing. But functions like `wilcox.test` work because they are S3 generic functions in R. Functions in R can dispatch based on the `class()` of the first parameter. You can see the version that runs with a formula with `stats:::wilcox.test.formula` and the "default" version with `stats:::wilcox.test.default`

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks this was basically what I looked for.